# Azure Blob Indexer ConnectionString SharedAccessSignature

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I am trying to use the Preview auf the Azure Search Blob Indexer. When configuring the indexer using a full connection string the indexer passes successfully (apart from the issues mentioned in my other questions).

What I am trying to do is to restrict the Indexer to use a SharedAccessSignature instead of the full ConnectionString.

The message I get with (status.LastResult.ErrorMessage) when querying the Indexer Status is following:

```
The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
```

I can reproduce this using the following sample code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var SASToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SASToken"];
        var endpoint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BlobEndpoint"];

        var sasToken = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(SASToken));
        var conn = $"BlobEndpoint={endpoint};SharedAccessSignature={sasToken};";
        var csa = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(conn);
        var blobClient = csa.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("main");

        // This throws an Error, 403 forbidden, as the SAS may not access the Container
        // none theless the indexer can still list blobs ...
        var exists = container.Exists();

        // ... as used here..
        var blobs = container.ListBlobs("documentArchive", true).ToList();
        foreach(var blob in blobs.OfType<CloudBlockBlob>())
        {
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(ms).Wait();
            var data = ms.ToArray();
            Console.WriteLine(blob.StorageUri);
        }
    }
```

My Assumption is that the Azure Search Indexer checks if the Container exists, gets an exception and then stops. I think this limitation is unnecessary and confusing as the blobs could still be enumerated and indexed correctly.

Comment: How are you creating the shared access signature?

Comment: Also, can you share the permissions you've included in your shared access signature?

Comment: @GauravMantri I will check tomorrow, but I think it has all permissions (rwdl, read, write, delete, list) on container level, will confirm tomorrow morning. Meanwhile, I think Eugene Shvets knows exactly why this isn't working ;) thank you anyhow!

Comment: Hi, I checked and the sp field had rwdl, so all permissions for modifying blobs in the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using a SAS URI as blob datasource credential is not currently supported. This is on our radar, please vote for [this UserVoice suggestion](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/12368244-support-shared-access-signature-for-blob-datasource) to help us prioritize this work. Thanks!